# C++11 lambdas capturing by reference trivially destructible

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, setjmp

I would like to know if the following leaks memory or not (specified by the standard)

```
...
jmp_buf env;
if(setjmp(env) == 0) {
    auto lambda = [&] () {
        ... 
        longjmp(env, 1);
    };
    lambda();
}
```

which boils down to whether lambdas capturing by reference have a trivial destructor (I guess)?

I know that this is probably wicked, but has to be done nevertheless.

Comment: Why in the world would you *ever* call `setjmp` and `longjmp`, in 2015, from C++?

Comment: @Griwes This is the way postgres handles exceptions and I am writing one in C++, as I am using a c++ library

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that PostgresSQL expects you to call setjmp(), and then its library invokes longjmp(). Any usage of setjmp/longjmp is likely internal to PostgresSQL's library, and shouldn't be of concern to anyone.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik when one calls ereport(ERROR, ..) a longjump will occur and all c++ objects that are on the stack and not POD will leak. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-c.html quote `If calling backend functions from C++ code, be sure that the C++ call stack contains only plain old data structures (POD). This is necessary because backend errors generate a distant longjmp() that does not properly unroll a C++ call stack with non-POD objects.`

Comment: That text is referencing postgresql extension code, not ordinary C++ code making regular postgresql calls. Postgresql's high level functions invoke setjmp(), and invoke various low-level functions. If you have an extension function compiled in, and it does whatever it does, and calls ereport(), ereport() executes a longjmp. Which, of course, you have to keep in mind if your extension code is written in C++. Are you implementing a PostgreSQL extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's implementation-specific. You may reasonably expect it to be true, but here's what the standard says (N4140, [expr.prim.lambda]/3, emphasis mine):

> An implementation may define the closure type differently from what is described below provided this does not alter the observable
>   behavior of the program other than by changing:
>    — the size and/or alignment of the closure type,
>    — **whether the closure type is trivially copyable** (Clause 9),
>    — whether the closure type is a standard-layout class (Clause 9), or
>    — whether the closure type is a POD class (Clause 9).

And by definition in [class]/3

> A *trivially copyable* class is a class that:
>    — has no non-trivial copy constructors (12.8),
>    — has no non-trivial move constructors (12.8),
>    — has no non-trivial copy assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8),
>    — has no non-trivial move assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8), and
>    — **has a trivial destructor** (12.4).

So, an implementation is allowed to create a non-trivial destructor for the lambda.

However, you can check if your particluar implementation made your particular lambda trivially destructible by the following:

```
auto lambda = [&]{ /*...*/ };
static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<decltype(lambda)>::value, "Lambda isn't trivially destructible");
```

Comment: Why is the destructor the only one described as trivial while everything else is "not non-trivial"?

Comment: "Has a trivial copy constructor" is not the same as "Has no non-trivial copy constructor", because it may have several. Whereas "Has a trivial destructor" is the same as "Has no non-trivial destructor", because it can only have one destructor, but the latter description is therefore unnecessarily wordy.